# Slow Left Outer Join

Tags: sql-server

I wonder if anyone can advise me on this issue.  I have a query which runs slowly when a left outer join is introduced.  Without the left outer join (Inner instead) it runs pretty much immediately, but with the left outer it runs 20 seconds or more.  The joined columns are indexed.  My execution plan shows a hash match if that helps.  Thank you again for your assistance..

Derek

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                dbo.Staff.strStaffName AS [Staff Name], dbo.Staff.strEmailAddress1 AS NegEmailAddress, ISNULL(dbo.qryContactEmailDJ.Address, 
                  dbo.Staff.strEmailAddress1) AS AppEmailAddress
FROM         dbo.Contacts INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Staff ON dbo.Contacts.strResponsibilityOf = dbo.Staff.strStaffName LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.qryContactEmailDJ ON dbo.Contacts.ContactPK = dbo.qryContactEmailDJ.ContactFK INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Property ON dbo.Contacts.CompanyFK = dbo.Property.CompanyFK INNER JOIN
                  dbo.qryLS_ApplicantLastMadeActive ON dbo.Contacts.ContactPK = dbo.qryLS_ApplicantLastMadeActive.ContactPK
WHERE     (dbo.Contacts.strApplicantStatus = 'Active') 
           AND (CONVERT(VarChar, dbo.qryLS_ApplicantLastMadeActive.LatestActiveDate, 112) = CONVERT(VarChar, GETDATE() - 84,112))
```

Comment: Please give the full execution plans (both versions of your query)

Comment: What data type is `LatestActiveDate` and why are you converting dates to strings? That prevents use of indexes?

Comment: why is distinct used here? which tables causes duplicate records?

Comment: Hi MatBailie,when I remove the qryLS_ApplicantLastMadeActive makes no difference really so I thought i'd leave it on for the purpose of this.  I will remove it and see if the execution plan changes

Comment: Potentially the dbo.qryContactEmailDJ has duplicates @sanatsathyan

Comment: How can I upload files with my execution plans on here?

Comment: you got it @DerekJee

Comment: I will reinvestigate..  THANK YOU !!!!

Comment: @DerekJee, upload execution plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and share the link here.

Answer (score 0):

This will make it a bit more readable and faster, the issue is your way of comparing the dates in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT --(do you really need distinct ?)
  Staff.strStaffName AS [Staff Name],
  Staff.strEmailAddress1 AS NegEmailAddress, 
  ISNULL(con.qryContactEmailDJ.Address, Staff.strEmailAddress1) AS AppEmailAddress
FROM dbo.Contacts
JOIN dbo.Staff
ON Contacts.strResponsibilityOf = Staff.strStaffName
LEFT JOIN dbo.qryContactEmailDJ con
ON Contacts.ContactPK = con.ContactFK
JOIN dbo.Property
ON Contacts.CompanyFK = Property.CompanyFK
JOIN dbo.qryLS_ApplicantLastMadeActive qryl
ON Contacts.ContactPK = qryl.ContactPK
WHERE
  (Contacts.strApplicantStatus = 'Active') 
  AND qryl.LatestActiveDate >= dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, GETDATE()), -84)
  AND qryl.LatestActiveDate < dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, GETDATE()), -83)
```

Comment: Super..  Thank you and I have made note of your date criteria.  Faster than converting it looks like.  The distinct is needed but (it is not my query) I can rewrite this minster not to use a distinct.  The case statement was also slowing it down..  Thank you for your comment and help..